# Does xsltproc "honor" the order and content specified in DTD?

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd, xmllint

I am trying to figure out if I am declaring my DTD elements correctly in an xml document. From everything I can tell, neither xsltproc or xmllint detect the validity errors in the following document:

```
<!DOCTYPE basic-dtd [
        <!ENTITY title "The Book of Love">
        <!ENTITY author "Jeffrey Halcomb">

        <!ELEMENT basic-dtd (title,author,subject,checked-out)>                                                                                                                   
        <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT checked-out EMPTY>
]>

<basic-dtd>
        <author>&author;</author>
        <title>&title;</title>
        <subject>A treatise on love as a driving elemental force in nature</subject>
        <checked-out>Yes</checked-out>
</basic-dtd>
```

In my doctype instruction, I (believe) I have specified:

- the correct order of elements in the basic-dtd element is title, author, subject, and checked-out.
- the element 'checked-out' should not contain any data (PCDATA,CDATA, or child elements)

And yet, when I run the following stylesheet against this xml (xsltproc basic-dtd.xsl basic-dtd.xml) , it reports no errors/warnings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >                                                                                                  
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:template match="/basic-dtd">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Likewise, when I run xmllint (xmllint --noent basic-dtd.xml) - it reports no errors.

xsltproc and xmllint (with --noent) do process the entities, and will error out if an unknown entity is used.

Am I using an apple-processor to transform/print orange-xml (wrong tool for the job), or is this a known feature?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I don't remember xsltproc doing validation. Did you try the `--valid` command line arg with xmllint?

Comment: YEAH!!! Thank-you!  That did the trick.  I think its interesting that one can use DTDs in stylesheets, schemas, etc... just to a limited extent:
- adding default/fixed values to elements, and
- using entities to create xsl:params/text in the output.

Comment: There's always the option of schema-aware XSLT processors like [Saxon PE/HE](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!schema-processing).

Comment: Added my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember xsltproc doing validation.

Try using the `--valid` command line arg with [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

There's also the option of using a schema/dtd-aware XSLT processor like [Saxon PE/HE](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!schema-processing).